# python print a list of lists of integers and strings without brackets

Tags: python, list

I want to print this primelist:

```
sublist=["a","b","c"] 
primelist=[sublist,["d",1,"e"],sublist]
```

I want this to be printed like that:

```
a;b;c 

d;1;e 

a;b;c
```

Here is my code:

```
for item in primelist: 
    print(";".join(item[0:]))
```

but I get this error:

```
>>> print(";".join(item[0:]))
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found
```

NOTE: if every item of the list is string then there is no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `1` is not a string. You can solve it, using `map(str, v)` for converting each item of a list `v` to string:

```
>>> [";".join(map(str, v)) for v in primelist]
['a;b;c', 'd;1;e', 'a;b;c']
```

Or:

```
for v in primelist:
    print ";".join(map(str, v))
```

Result:

```
a;b;c
d;1;e
a;b;c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print primelist[1:-1]
```

might be enough

or more likely

```
print ";".join(map(str,primelist))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [1,2,3]

print ';'.join(i for i in map(str,s))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs in your line `print(";".join(item[0:]))`.  Since 1 is not a string in `["d', 1, "e"]` the .join() function fails.  To fix:

```
for item in primelist: 
    print(";".join(map(str, item)))
```